# Increasing Excel 2010 memory allocation

Tags: java, excel, java-native-interface

I am running a java process inside Excel 2010 through a library which use the JNI to run it.

My machine is largely sufficient for what I need, but Excel 2010 starts with little memory and sometimes my JVM creation fails with message: "Failed to create JVM, could not reserve requested memory"

How can I increase the heap size for EXCEL? What forces JNI to run the java code in Excel memory space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need a 64-bit version of excel.  Running a 32-bit version of Java is difficult enough as it need a continuous region of memory.

If you had a 64-bit version of excel, it would be able to use as much memory as you need.

An alternative is to start a Java process and communicate with it via sockets.  This means it will not be limited by excel, but what your OS can do for the process. e.g. it can be 64-bit even if excel is 32-bit.

Comment: can you detail it why Java need a continous regin of memory?

Comment: When you start the JVM, it allocates a continuous region of memory so it can manage the memory itself.  It need to do this as the JVM manages the memory not the native allocator.  There are many advantages to doing this (performance and simplicity), but the disadvantage is you need continuous virtual memory.

Comment: @Edmondo1984 Added an alternative which is to use a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

A macro of mine should copy data from a program (UVprobe) to Excel.
This is done by ‘Application.SendKeys "^c"’ to copy data from Uvprobe and ‘Application.SendKeys "^v"’  to insert data in Excel.

This entails shifting from UVprobe to Excel a lot of times. After a short time Excel freezes "Excel (not responding)"
I made this little testprogram which also creates the error after only 3 loops

```
Sub Apptest()

For i = 1 To 10

    AppActivate "notepad"
    Sleep 1000
    AppActivate "Excel"
    Sleep 1000
Next i
```

End sub

If I put in “Word” instead of Application.caption I don’t get any error. What can be the reason ?
It seems that Excel fills up the memory, but I can’t see what uses memory in the test program.

Comment: Forgot to tell the macro is in VBA